# Force-install AVG 2011 along-side Avast

Tags: command-line, avg-antivirus, avast

When trying to install the latest version of AVG, you are forced to uninstall Avast to proceed.

Does anyone know if there is a switch that the installer can be run with to bypass this? Something like: `LastestAVGInstaller.exe /force`

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Generally you don't want two AntiVirus programs installed on a computer. They will see each others malware definitions and fight each other.

Comment: I'm just trying to help a friend who insists on having "Double Protection". I've explained that having two anti-virus programs is less than ideal (for reasons MHrappstead explained), but they insist.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure I would help this person.  They're asking for your expertise.  You know multiple AV programs will interfere, provide less protection, degrade performance, and risk corrupting data by trying to access the same file at the same time.  They came to you for your expertise.  Your expertise says not to do it.  They don't want your expertise now.  Let them be.  It sounds harsh, but it's professional.  If you were a doctor or an engineer, you'd be ethically bound not to do anything here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fast CPU its fine to have more AV, also u can switch on and off AV modules and redistribute it for different tasks.

Im not sure if its true that more AVs scaning one file is more risk, best would be to get one good AV and done instead walling PC like crazy.

If not sure about your AV detection, try HitmanPro.